# How can I fix the "class variable @@debug_missing_translation of ActionView::Base is overtaken by Object" error when running any task with ruby 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to upgrade a Rails 6.1.3.1 application from Ruby 2.6.6 to 3.0.0

All the rspec tests run fine and the in development everything seems to work just fine except one thing:
Even the simplest of tasks fails with this error:
"class variable @@debug_missing_translation of ActionView::Base is overtaken by Object"

For example, this simpletask.rake file

```
task simpletask: :environment do
  puts 'Hello'
end
```

is not able to run as I get the following error:

```
lxxx@xxx:~/Workspace/edumino$ rails simpletask
rails aborted!
class variable @@debug_missing_translation of ActionView::Base is overtaken by Object
/home/xxx/railsapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xxx/railsapp/bin/rails:5:in `require'
/home/xxx/railsapp/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xxx/railsapp/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/home/xxx/railsapp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/xxx/railsapp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => simpletask => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

...so, it turns out the problem was an already existing task. I don't remember exactly why this was necessary but the task had this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/cron_helper"
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/notifier_helper"
require "#{Rails.root}/app/helpers/application_helper"
include ApplicationHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
include CronHelper

namespace :cron do
  task sms: :environment do |_t, _args|
    ...
  end
end
```

I assume that the  guilty code was including the ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper

Again, I can't remember why I had to do that at that time. But if you bump into this kind of 'overtaken by' error when upgrading to Ruby 3.0, check your other tasks and see what kinda weird includes you might have had. In my case, since I didn't need the old task, I just removed it.

Comment: Great answer thank you. Ran into a similar issue when upgrading from Ruby 2.7.5 to 3.0.6 running on Rails 6.1.7.4. Was seeing `class variable @@local_levels of ActiveSupport::Logger is overtaken by Object (RuntimeError)`. Given the lack of info online it had to be something specific to our project. In looking at our code we had a file that was doing a `include ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` which we just removed and fixed the problem.